# Implement a counter which resets in python panda data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I would like to implement a counter which counts the number of successive zero observations in a dataframe (across multiple columns). But I would like to reset it if a non-zero observation is found. I have used a for loop but it is incredibly slow, I am sure there must be far more efficient ways. This is my code:

Here is a snapshot of df

```
df.head()

                  ACL       ACT       ADH       ADR       AFE  AFH       AFT  
2013-02-05       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN   
2013-02-12 -0.136861 -0.020406  0.046150  0.000000 -0.005321  NaN  0.058195   
2013-02-19 -0.006632  0.041665  0.007365  0.012738  0.040930  NaN -0.037818   
2013-02-26 -0.023848 -0.023999 -0.030677 -0.003144  0.050604  NaN -0.047604   
2013-03-05  0.009771 -0.024589 -0.021073 -0.039432  0.047315  NaN  0.068727
```

I first initialise an empty data frame which has the same properties of df (dataframe) above

```
df1=pd.DataFrame( index= df, columns=df)
df1=df1.fillna(0)
```

Then I create my function which iterates over the rows, but this only deals with one column at a time

```
def zero_obs(x=df,y=df1):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == 0:
           y[i] = y[i-1] + 1
        else:
            y[i] = 0
    return y 

for col in df.columns:
    df1[col] = zero_obs(x=df[col],y=df1[col])
```

Really appreciate any help!!

The output i expect is as follows:

```
df1.tail()
            BRN  AXL  TTO  AGL  ACL
2017-01-03    3  125    0    0    0
2017-01-10    0  126    0    0    0
2017-01-17    1  127    0    0    0
2017-01-24    0  128    0    0    0
2017-01-31    0  129    1    0    0
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hi John, please see the initial question, i have updated with the expected outcome, which is a dataframe (df1) with the counter output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***setup***
Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.zeros((10, 2), dtype=int),
    columns=list('AB')
)
df.loc[[0, 4, 8], 'A'] = 1
df.loc[6, 'B'] = 1
print(df)

   A  B
0  1  0
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  0  0
4  1  0
5  0  0
6  0  1
7  0  0
8  1  0
9  0  0
```

***Option 1***
`pandas` `apply`

```
def zero_obs(x):
    """`x` is assumed to be a `pd.Series`"""
    csum = x.eq(0).cumsum()
    cpos = csum.where(x.ne(0)).ffill().fillna(0)
    return csum.sub(cpos)

print(df.apply(zero_obs))

     A    B
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  3.0  4.0
4  0.0  5.0
5  1.0  6.0
6  2.0  0.0
7  3.0  1.0
8  0.0  2.0
9  1.0  3.0
```

***Option 2***
don't use `apply`

This function works just as well on `df`

```
zero_obs(df)

     A    B
0  0.0  1.0
1  1.0  2.0
2  2.0  3.0
3  3.0  4.0
4  0.0  5.0
5  1.0  6.0
6  2.0  0.0
7  3.0  1.0
8  0.0  2.0
9  1.0  3.0
```

Comment: the function is a bit problematic when the initial observation is non-zero

Comment: @blala82 I observed the same thing.  The post has already been updated.  Try the function I have now.